# Inventory Material ID and Oracle Install Base

Tags: oracle, oracleapplications

1) Does inventory material transaction ID get populated when any standard transaction is made in oracle install base.

2) I defined a custom transaction type and passing that to public API,at that time material transaction ID is not getting populated.

Please let me know whether material transaction ID is populated only to standard transactions or also for custom transactions

Comment: This is Oracle Applications - Inventory specific question.

Answer (score 0):

For each and every transaction done in Inventory material transaction ID is populated that you can check in Inventory >> transactions >> material transactions..